# How to extract href= and title values using javascript similar to PHP's preg_match_all()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I got an HTML string as :var code; I want to extract all values of href and title similar to using PHP's `preg_match_all()`. I have done a similar thing in PHP as the example shown but wondering how I can do that in JavaScript and have all href and title values in array as PHP example ?

Note: initial value of `$input` is blocks of div like example below:

```
<div class="up"  rel="1234" id="up1234" style="float:right">
<div class="pic" style='border:3px solid #cacaca' >
 <a href="/episode 14" title="episode 14">
    <img src="images/image14.jpg" alt="watch episode 14"  />
 </a> 
</div>
<a href="/episode 14" title="episode 14 "class="title">watch episode 14</a> 
<div class="data" style="height:auto">watch episode 14 </div>
<center>
 <a href="episode14" title="episode 14" class="data" id="play_me1234">
 <img src="/images/image14.jpg" alt="watch episode 14"/>
 </a>
</center>
    </div>

preg_match_all('#href\s*=\s*"(.*)"#siU', $input, $foo1);
preg_match_all("#class=\"title\">([^<]+)</a>#", $input, $foo2);

$i = -1;
$foo1[1] = array_unique($foo1[1]);
 foreach($foo1[1] as $k => $v ){
  //echo $v;


 $i++;
echo '<a href="./doit.php?Id='.$v.'&title='.$foo2[1][$i].'"> '.$foo2[1][$i].' </a> <br />' ;
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide the initial value of `$input`?

Comment: Google for javascript regular expressions?

Comment: thanks for reply guys. Vision i posted a sample of input above!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pattern = /<a href="([^"]+?)" title="[^"]+?" class="title">([^<]+?)<\/a>/gi;
    code = code.match(pattern);
    for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        document.write(code[i].replace(pattern, '<a href="./doit.php?Id=$1&title=$2">$2</a><br />'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Many Thanks guys. Gio your solution worked well but i wondering how your solution avoided duplicate href values ? as you seen in above example there duplicates of href values in sample html! Furthermore, may i know why the page that i run the script keeps saying "connecting..." in firefox browser(in tab title) even the script finished loading the output!

Comment: Glad it helped! After analyzing the code I realized that to avoid duplicates only the links with `class="title"` are needed, so I just ignored the rest. Not sure about your browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `code.match(/your regex here/g)`. The `g` modifier changes how `match` behaves so that it returns an array of full matches as opposed to just the first match, at the cost of losing the subpatterns. You can get them subpatterns back by matching the match against the regex again but this time without the modifier.

That said, you could just parse the DOM instead. If you have the HTML in an element, you can use `querySelectorAll("[href]")` to find elements with an `href` attribute and loop through them. Similarly, use `querySelectorAll(".title")` to find "title" elements more reliably.